# Openni_node.launch in Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been having the same problem as this post (http://answers.ros.org/question/39814/openni_nodelaunch-not-found/), but when I changed the kinect+rgbdslam.launch file to depend on openni_camera_deprecated, I got this error:

error loading  tag:
file does not exist [/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/openni_params.yaml]
XML is

What is going wrong? I would greatly appreciate an explanation on how to fix this problem, which occurs when running any Fuerte program that depends on openni_node.launch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40331/openni_node.launch-in-fuerte/) by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a bug in the launch script in the openni_camera_deprecated package. See https://kforge.ros.org/openni/trac/ticket/51

I would recommend taking either of these options

- Update your code to use the new launch script in the openni_launch stack (or create a subset of this script yourself, as it launches way too many nodelets for my comfort)
- Download a local copy of the openni_camera_deprecated package in your workspace, and apply the fix mentioned in the bug report.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1